# networkd3.js data massaging at frontend vs backend?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am working on a networkd3.js library. I am getting back objects like this one from my rest calls:

```
{
   fromNode: "xyz",
   toNode: "abc",
   currencyAmount: 123,
   edgeTypeCode: "U ",
}
```

Now i need to convert this to the equivalent data structure what d3 sankey chart will need. Following is an example of an equivalent object for the above response object:

```
{
  "source":17, "target":18, "value":50
}
```

The source and the target contains the index of the nodes, and not the node labels. Hence, once i get my response, I will have to massage it, create a list and add indices and then map them onto my response so that I will have the exact data structure required.

Now I have two options:

```
a. Do the massaging at the back end at the database level.
b. Do the changes at the client side( massage the data) using AngularJS
```

My question is which one is faster? what will be better in terms of time complexity and rendering the network onto the UI?

Comment: When I did something similar the data came in the latter format from the database, which generated it via PL/SQL. The list of nodes contained their ids and those were referenced in the list of links as `source` and `target`. I would expect that the second format would be faster, at the very least because there is less data being passed (less than half in your example) which would also save on bandwidth. That said, I find client-side manipulation easier to work with and d3 has many useful functions for that. That may just be a result of my varying experience levels with the languages, though.

Comment: @JSBob thanks for your reply. In fact the first approach also totally contradicts the design patterns and paradigms of the REST services. If i try to do all the data massaging at the server level and accordingly manipulate the data to be sent as response, that may help me with d3 library but not with some other. Also, to capture the index of nodes at server level, I will have to repeat the same lengthy query which I will be doing for calculating the links. That will add tremendous overhead time to my REST service response time.